# mvc controller single responsibility principle and POST requests

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, post, controller

I am interested in the correct/standard/advised approach for an django web application I am currently developing.
I have practical experience in programming, but I am worried about the efficiency of my implementation, since I don't have too much theoretical knowledge of MVC and related principles.

I have several forms that must fetch various amounts of information from my database (via AJAX POST requests), all related to a single action the user would take (for example: to buy a house, the system would need information about the house, the client, the previous owner, the method of payment, etc.).
Because of this, the POST requests would be very frequent in one page.

My question is: 
should I have one controller responsible for each different "type" of POST request (one controller for the "house" requests, one for the "client", etc.), or is it ok to have one "sale data fetcher" controller that handles all related POST requests checks via one of the parameters of each request and communicate with the model accordingly?

I apologize if am not using the question system correctly, this is my first question here.

**EDIT: total lapse in my question!!! Yes the App is in PYTHON, I did use PHP for a previous Project.**

Thanks in advance! stack overflow has been a lifesaver so many times.

Comment: I'm very curious how development is going on that Django PHP web application of yours, especially considering that Django is a *Python web framework* and has nothing to do with PHP!

Comment: @Francis Avila: yes you are totally correct. My mistake, I just mixed things up inadvertently. I did use PHP and CakePHP for a previous Project, but this current one is in Python, the Framework is Django, and the database PostgreSQL. I have edited the question. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case you will want to have a separate controller for each 'type' of request. This helps in keeping the code simple, without having to deal with any 'special cases', and in general easier to reuse.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I think you are right, and I suspected that was the correct way, even though I had already implemented some controllers the other way, but since I wasn't sure, I was hoping someone could provide some theorical justification or documentation for which was the preferred way.
I'd upvote you but I can't yet :/

Comment: perhaps I will wait for a Little bit to see if someone can provide another perspective/source before accepting your answer, is that ok?

Comment: Sure. Also note that another approach you might want to consider in order to limit number of HTTP requests, is to have the controller gather all data required for given page, wrap it in one large JSON string, then split it into individual data objects browser-side. That's a bit convoluted, and in majority of cases just not needed, but sometimes can be handy.